# converting a string into false Boolean value

Tags: python, logical-operators

I want to know how I can get a string value to convert into a False bool value, because every time I run the code it returns a True value.

```
high_income = input(“Do you have a high income?:”)
credit = input(“Do you have a credit line?”)
If high_income and credit: 
      Print(“eligible for loan”)
else:
     print(“not eligible”)
```

Comment: input always return string and not-empty string always gives `True` - you should compare ie. `high_income.lower() == 'yes' and credit.lower() == "yes"`

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement evaluates what you give it as a boolean (`bool`) and acts on its truth value. If a string is evaluated as a boolean, the empty string `''` is `False` and any non-empty string is `True`.

So, whatever you enter, it will always evaluate to `True`, unless you enter nothing.

What you want is to evaluate a specific string, so you have two options; the first is to directly check for the strings that mean 'True':

```
if high_income.lower() in ['yes', 'y', 'true']:
```

Note that `.lower()` causes the answer to be converted to lower case, so `'Yes'` is also `True`.

The second is to evaluate what the user typed and use that value:

```
if eval(high_income):
```

But this is generally a bad idea, since whatever the user types will be evaluated as a valid Python expression and this can cause unexpected results or even unsafe situations. Also, if the users types `2+2`, that's also `True`, since it evaluates to an integer value of `4` and any integer value that is not `0` is always `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
high_income = input("Do you have a high income?:")    
credit = input("Do you have a credit line?")   
if high_income == 'yes' and credit == 'yes':  

      print("ligible for loan")
else:

     print("not eligible")
#output
#Do you have a high income?:yes
#Do you have a credit line?yes
#ligible for loan
```